codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape (Python QREADER)
I was trying out the python qreader module but everytime i try to run it i get the SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape error.
from qreader import QReader
from cv2 import QRCodeDetector, imread
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

# Initialize the three tested readers (QRReader, OpenCV and pyzbar)
qreader_reader, cv2_reader, pyzbar_reader = QReader(), QRCodeDetector(), decode

for img_path in ('C:\Users\Blabla\Desktop\code\python_shit\out.png'):
    # Read the image
    img = imread(img_path)

    # Try to decode the QR code with the three readers
    qreader_out = qreader_reader.detect_and_decode(image=img)
    cv2_out = cv2_reader.detectAndDecode(img=img)[0]
    pyzbar_out = pyzbar_reader(image=img)
    # Read the content of the pyzbar output (double decoding will save you from a lot of wrongly decoded characters)
    pyzbar_out = tuple(out.data.data.decode('utf-8').encode('shift-jis').decode('utf-8') for out in pyzbar_out)

    # Print the results
    print(f"Image: {img_path} -> QReader: {qreader_out}. OpenCV: {cv2_out}. pyzbar: {pyzbar_out}.")


how can i fix this?
Im kinda lost rn i dont know what to do

\U is a special character in python strings.  Use a raw string instead, to make it not special.  Put an r in front, like this: r'C:\Users\...'

Or you can use forward-slashes instead of backslashes.  Yes, they work on Windows.  'C:/Users/...'

when i dot that it just says [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'

This question is similar to: "Unicode Error 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes..." when writing Windows file paths. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it just says [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C' Show us the full filename string you used.

it just doesent work when i add r behind the C
